# Group by in SQL using first two digits

Tags: sql

I have a column storing codes like `71xxxx`, `78xxxx`, `59xxxx`, and so on. I need to run a query to find out all the records that have codes starting with `71`.

I mean, all the rows where the the first two digits of the code column are 71. If anyone can share the SQL query for this, I would be really helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: is this for mysql, oracle, sql server etc?  if you provide the names of your fields, some sample data, we can help tailor a solution.  Please also put forth anything you have tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `like` in a `where` clause for the filtering:

```
where code like '71%'
```

This is pretty basic SQL.  If you are not familiar with it, you should study the language a bit more.

Comment: Thank you. It worked!! I have just started using SQL, and after searching for a while I was trying group by function.

Comment: I was about to say substr(code,1,2) = '71' was more efficient... boy was I wrong. Using a table I have with "CODE" as the lead part of a three level index, in my particular case the "LIKE" was able to use the index, whereas the "SUBSTR" ended up with a full table scan. My table has 284 million rows, guess which one I like better? Seriously, it is dependent upon your data, but it was good for me to find out the LIKE uses the index whereas the SUBSTR does not.

Comment: @BrianLeach . . . I remember when I learned that.  You should note that `LIKE` generally only uses the index when the pattern does not start with a wildcard (although Oracle could implement a skip-scan if the pattern starts with `_`).

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
select substr(col, 1,2),count(*)  from ITEM group by substr(col, 1,2)
```